# Implementing Picasso not loading image

Tags: android, image, sqlite

After I decided to implement [Universal Image Loader](https://github.com/nostra13/Android-Universal-Image-Loader), because I had implemented a method that convert `URL` to `Drawable`, but since I don't know how many images it will return my `SQLite` query I decided to implement an `Image Loader`...
The thing is I'm stuck at the moment, cause I thought I did all what the `GitHub` say but at the time I load the `Image` it stays white and never loads.

On my `Adapter class` I've changed the line of the `drawable` as :

```
Picasso.with(context)
            .load(Uri.parse(String.valueOf(item.icon)))
            .resize(180, 180)
            .placeholder(R.drawable.ic_launcher).into(viewHolder.ivIcon);
```

It works, beucase it shows yo me the ic_launcher icon... but never changes to the real image.

On my class where I fetch the data I have this (on my OnCreate()) :

```
   new Thread(new Runnable() {
                @Override
                public void run() {
                    try {
                        Thread.sleep(2000);


                    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }

                    new MyAsyncTask().execute();

                    getActivity().runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {

                        @Override
                        public void run() {
                    //   progress.dismiss();
                        }
                    });
                }

            }).start();
        }
```

Then I created an inner class where I fetch the data into my `ListView`... but it doesn't works. I don't know If I've to delte those methods since I've changed it to `Picasso`.

```
private class MyAsyncTask extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void> {
    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
    }

    @Override
    protected Void doInBackground(Void... params) {

        Conexion = new MarketSQLite(getActivity(), "market", null, 1);
        mItems = new ArrayList<ListViewItem>();

        db = Conexion.getReadableDatabase();

        Cursor c;

        c = db.rawQuery("Select NOM_OFER,PREU_OFERTA,DATA_F,FOTO,PERCENTDESCOMPTE from T_OFERTA", null);
        c.moveToFirst();
        if (c != null) {
            do {
                for (int i = 0; i < c.getColumnCount(); i++) {
                    Title = c.getString((c.getColumnIndex("NOM_OFER")));
                    Preu = c.getColumnIndex("PREU_OFERTA");
                    percent = c.getString((c.getColumnIndex("PERCENTDESCOMPTE")));
                    data_f = c.getString((c.getColumnIndex("DATA_F")));
                    URLTest = c.getString((c.getColumnIndex("FOTO")));
                    FOTO = Imagehandler(URLTest);
                    Log.e("", "" + c.getString(i));

                    // initialize and set the list adapter


                   // Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "Title" + Title + "Preu" + Preu + "Percent" + percent + "Cheese is " + data_f, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                }
                mItems.add(new ListViewItem(FOTO, Title, Preu.toString(), percent, data_f));


            }while (c.moveToNext());
        }
        c.close();

return null;
    }


    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(Void result) {
        super.onPostExecute(result);
        myAdapter = new ListViewDemoAdapter(getActivity(), mItems);
        setListAdapter(myAdapter);
    }
}
```

Where `ImageHandler` is a method that I've created before this is :

```
 protected Drawable Imagehandler(String url) {
        try {
            url=url.replaceAll(" ", "%20");
            InputStream is = (InputStream)this.fetch(url);
            Drawable d = Drawable.createFromStream(is, "src");
            return d;
        } catch (MalformedURLException e)
        {
            System.out.println(url);
            System.out.println("error at URI"+e);
            return null;
        }
        catch (IOException e)
        {
            System.out.println("io exception: "+e);
            System.out.println("Image NOT FOUND");
            return null;
        }
    }

    protected Object fetch(String address) throws MalformedURLException,IOException {
        URL url = new URL(address);
        Object content = url.getContent();
        return content;
    }
```

I don't know why isn't the image loading on my ListView if it shows all of the rest of data...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of Drawable, try to get url string in your adapter like

Change From

```
public ListViewItem(Drawable icon, String title, String precio, String descuento, String date) {
    this.icon = icon;
    this.title = title;
    this.precio = precio;
    this.descuento = descuento;
    this.date = date;
}
```

To

```
    public ListViewItem(String icon_url, String title, String precio, String descuento, String date) {
        this.icon_url = icon_url;
        this.title = title;
        this.precio = precio;
        this.descuento = descuento;
        this.date = date;
    }
```

and use Picasso where you are loading your imageview like this -

```
Picasso.with(context)
            .load(icon_url))
            .resize(180, 180)
            .placeholder(R.drawable.ic_launcher).into(viewHolder.ivIcon);
```

1) Your ListViewItem class should be like this -

```
public class ListViewItem {
    public final String icon;       // the drawable for the ListView item ImageView
    public final String title;       // the text for the ListView item title
    public final String precio;      // the price for the ListView item
    public final String descuento;   // the price for the discount for the ListView item
    public final String date;        //the date for the sale for the ListView item

     // the text for the ListView item description

    public ListViewItem(String icon_url, String title, String precio, String descuento, String date) {
        this.icon = icon_url;
        this.title = title;
        this.precio = precio;
        this.descuento = descuento;
        this.date = date;
    }
}
```

2) ListViewDemoAdapterClass

```
public class ListViewDemoAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<ListViewItem> {
Context context;
    public ListViewDemoAdapter(Context context, List<ListViewItem> items) {
        super(context, R.layout.listview_item, items);
        this.context = context;
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        ViewHolder viewHolder;

        if(convertView == null) {
            // inflate the GridView item layout
            LayoutInflater inflater = LayoutInflater.from(getContext());
            convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.listview_item, parent, false);

            // initialize the view holder
            viewHolder = new ViewHolder();
            viewHolder.ivIcon = (ImageView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.ivIcon);
            viewHolder.tvTitle = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.tvTitle);
            viewHolder.tvPrice = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.tvPrice);
            viewHolder.tvDiscount = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.tvDiscount);
            viewHolder.tvDate = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.tvDatas);
            convertView.setTag(viewHolder);
        } else {
            // recycle the already inflated view
            viewHolder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
        }

        // update the item view
        ListViewItem item = getItem(position);
        Picasso.with(context)
                .load(item.icon)
                .resize(180, 180)
                .placeholder(R.drawable.ic_launcher).into(viewHolder.ivIcon);
        viewHolder.tvTitle.setText(item.title);
        viewHolder.tvDiscount.setText(item.descuento);
        viewHolder.tvPrice.setText(item.precio);
        viewHolder.tvDate.setText(item.date);

        return convertView;
    }


    private static class ViewHolder {
        ImageView ivIcon;
        TextView tvTitle;
        TextView tvDiscount;
        TextView tvPrice;
        TextView tvDate;
    }
}
```

3. ListFragment code, just add this

   ```
     Cursor c; 

    c = db.rawQuery("Select 
   NOM_OFER,PREU_OFERTA,DATA_F,FOTO,PERCENTDESCOMPTE from T_OFERTA", null); 
   c.moveToFirst(); 
   if (c != null) { 
   do { 
   for (int i = 0; i < c.getColumnCount(); i++) { 
   Title = c.getString((c.getColumnIndex("NOM_OFER"))); 
   Preu = c.getColumnIndex("PREU_OFERTA"); 
   percent = c.getString((c.getColumnIndex("PERCENTDESCOMPTE"))); 
   data_f = c.getString((c.getColumnIndex("DATA_F"))); 
   URLTest = c.getString((c.getColumnIndex("FOTO")));
   ```

Hope this helps :)

Answer (score 2):

you just need to add your picasso code snippet as the following in your ImageHandler method and nothing else-

```
Picasso.with(context)
            .load(url))
            .resize(180, 180)
            .placeholder(R.drawable.ic_launcher).into(your_imageview);
```

you don't need to download the image or make the bitmap or convert that into drawable to load from url. hope this helps you.

Comment: My url is not on the same class, I mean the url I get when I make a query of my SQLite

Comment: that should not a problem. you retrieve the url from anywhere, then just load the url. just one thing to be clear URI & URL is not same thing.

Comment: But I've to define the url... and it's on my other class